# 'UnitOfWork._mandateRepository' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am implementing Repository and UnitOfWork in ASP.NET Core Web API.

I have this code:

DBContext:

```
public class DDMDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DDMDbContext(DbContextOptions<DDMDbContext> options)
    : base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<Mandate> Mandates { get; set; }
}
```

Model is shown below:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Mandate : EntityBase
{
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

IBaseRepository:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();
}
```

BaseRepository:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _entities;

    public BaseRepository(DDMDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        var list = await _entities.ToListAsync();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Then Finally the UnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IBaseRepository<Mandate> MandateRepository { get; }

    void SaveChanges();
    Task SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(DDMDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    #region Mandate
    private readonly IBaseRepository<Mandate> _mandateRepository;

    public IBaseRepository<Mandate> MandateRepository => _mandateRepository ?? new BaseRepository<Mandate>(_context);
    # endregion

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_context != null)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue now is that, when I was going through the code in IUnitOfWork.

I got this warning:

> Then I have this message: 'UnitOfWork._mandateRepository' is never assigned to.

**_mandateRepository** is highlighted in

> private readonly IBaseRepository _mandateRepository;

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The message is very clear, what's your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This line only always returns a new BaseRepository, because _mandateRepository never gets set.

```cs
public IBaseRepository<Mandate> MandateRepository => _mandateRepository ?? new BaseRepository<Mandate>(_context);
```

What you actually want to do is

```cs
public IBaseRepository<Mandate> MandateRepository
{
  get 
  {
    if (_mandateRepository == null)
    {
      _mandateRepository = new BaseRepository<Mandate>(_context);
    }
    return _mandateRepository;
  }
}
```

This way, _mandateRepository is initialized once. You'll have to remove the readonly modifier though.

Comment: Do you mean I should remove readonly from:   private readonly IBaseRepository<Mandate> _mandateRepository;

Comment: yes, otherwise you can't set it at runtime, like in the example above.

Comment: Do I need to remove readonly from this too    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;

Comment: no, because it's set in the constructor. the constructor and the initializer are the only places you may set a readonly field or a get-only property.